# Write topic data from Redis-sink-connector to redis container

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect, publish

We are looking for sending topic data from Kafka Redis sink connector to a docker redis container. The connector state is showing running, and it connected with topic as well , still I am not getting data in the container. I am checking with Keys * command which is showing "empty array".

Please check the configuration and let me know if i am missing any thing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34Qe.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaGQc.png)

Any configuration changes required in kafka-sink connector configuration?
How to debugin case of no error?
How to check data redis-container?